# Service makemigrations has neither an image nor a build context specified

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Hello I am trying to make workable a project. But when I run the following instruction : 
`docker-compose up` I got the following error :

`ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service makemigrations has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.`

Here is the yml file `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        expose:
            - "5432"
        environment:
            - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/myproject/
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
            - "3000:3000"
        depends_on: 
            - db
            - makemigrations
            - migrations
    makemigrations:
        command: python manage.py makemigrations --noinput
        volumes:
            - .:/myproject/
        depends_on: 
            - db
    migrations:
        command: python manage.py migrate --noinput
        volumes:
            - .:/myproject/
        depends_on: 
            - db
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: The error message pretty much means what it says: what image is Compose supposed to run that command against?